# External Users access and Block IP range for Internet facing site for SP Online and AZURE (On-Prem)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, azure

We have SharePoint 2013 Environment License E1 with P2 and need assistance of below question 
1) In our application, we want to provide access to External users they don't have license, Is it possible In SharePoint Online?

It would be really good if anyone provide any pointers/suggestions on this

Comment: Most of the times it is much better to post multiple questions instead if adding 4-5 in the same question. The risk now is that no one knows the answer to all of your questions and hence do not answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is very good step by step article from Microsoft, how to block and grant access to the certain IP from IIS.

Hope it will help you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324066

Comment: As said before, stop posting only links as answers! You need to elaborate more, and make your answers more independent on the link. The link should be a reference, and possibly a source of deeper information, but the main steps you need to take should be clear in your post.